# How do I compare float values among lists, which is in the each key of the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, I have this:

```
mydict = {0: ['ID1', 46, 10, 2.0], 1: ['ID2', 23, 9, 1.85]}
```

I would like to know how to make comparisons of the forth value for the 2 lists through accessing the keys of the dictionary.

Below codes is what I have tried but I cannot get the forth item (float value) in the list to compare:

```
 for val in mydict.keys():
    for item in mydict[val]:
       print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the list you don't need an internal loop, just get it right by index.
The code may look like:

```
mydict = {0: ['ID1', 46, 10, 2.0], 1: ['ID2', 23, 9, 1.85]}

prev = -1
isChecked = False

for key in mydict.keys():
    myList = mydict[key]
    if(isChecked):
        print(prev == myList[3])
    else:
        isChecked = True
    prev = myList[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since python is a 0-based language, `lst[3]` is the fourth number.

So try:

`mydict[0][3] == mydict[1][3]`

and this will be true if and only if the fourth elements are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mydict = {0: ['ID1', 46, 10, 2.0], 1: ['ID2', 23, 9, 1.85]}
# just show the entries for keys 1 & 2
print(f'{mydict[0][3]} and  {mydict[1][3]}')
# or - loop over the keys:
for k in mydict.keys():
    print(f'{mydict[k][3]}')
```